# Return two Strings from method

Tags: java, string

I'm a beginner in Java programming, and I'm trying to make a voting machine program, where you can vote for Republicans or Democrats. My question is, how can I edit my method so I would be able to return two strings with two distinct values?

For example, look at my code all the way in the bottom. It's wrong, but I wanted the tester to be able to print out Democrats: (some number) and Republicans: (some number) in one method. How can I do that?

```
import java.lang.String;

public class VotingMachine1 {
    private double Democrats;
    private double Republicans;

    public VotingMachine1() {
        Democrats = 0;
        Republicans = 0;
    }

    public void voteRepublican() {
        Republicans = Republicans + 1;
    }

    public void voteDemocrat() {
        Democrats = Democrats + 1;
    }

    public void clearMachineState() {
        Republicans = 0;
        Democrats = 0;
    }

    //this is where I'm having difficulties. I know its wrong
    public double getTallies() {
        System.out.println("Democrats: ", return Democrats);
        System.out.println("Republicans: ", return Republicans);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about the downvotes. Some users believe that the site should accept only "expert" questions. That may be, but it's not my opinion. Perhaps we should rank/tag questions so each one sees only questions to his/her liking. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No return is necessary there, since you aren't leaving a function. To do what you seem to want to do, just replace that last method with the following:

```
public void getTallies()
{
    System.out.println("Democrats: " + Double.toString(Democrats));      
    System.out.println("Republicans: " + Double.toString(Republicans));
}
```

Also, since your votecounts should only ever be integers, there's no reason to declare them as doubles instead of ints.

Comment: the machine won't let me use the println statement, why not?

Comment: That's not really enough information for anyone to help you with it. What error message do you get, or what happens when you try to use it?

Comment: @RoyKesserwani The System.out.println method will only needs 1 parameter you have 2.

Comment: No, there's only one parameter given to it in this code. "Democrats: " + Double.toString(Democrats) is a single string.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for here is a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#summary). A format string is used when you know what your output should look like, and only have a few "holes" where unknown data should be filled in. To output your data using format strings, you would use the [`System.out.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
System.out.format("Democrats: %f\n", Democrats);      
System.out.format("Republicans: %f\n", Republicans);
```

In this case, the `%f` indicates that a floating-point number (since your variables are declared as `double`) will be printed instead of the `%f`. However, you may wish to consider declaring them as `int` (or `long`) instead, in which case you would use `%d` instead of `%f` in the format strings.

Finally, you ought to change your `getTallies()` method to return `void` instead of `double`, as you are printing the values, not returning them.

Answer (score 3):

Your code and your description are so contradictory, it is not clear that you even know what you are *trying* to do.  I believe that this is the *real root* of your problems.

Here goes:

```
    public double getTallies() 
    {
       System.out.println("Democrats: ", return Democrats);      
       System.out.println("Republicans: ", return Republicans);
    }
```

First, your question says that you want to "return two strings with two values" ... but you have declared the method as returning one `double`.

Next, your code is *printing* values ... not returning them.

---

You've also made some major mistakes at the syntactic level, largely (I believe) because you are trying to do contradictory things:

- `return Republicans` is not a valid Java expression, so you can't use it as a argument to the `println` method.
- The `println` method can't be called with two arguments, as your code is trying to do.  There is a zero argument version and a number of one argument overloads ... but no overloads with two or more arguments.

---

Basically, you need to *start* by ***making up your mind*** about what this method is supposed to do.  Is it supposed to:

- return the tallies (as two doubles)?
- return a string representing the two tallies?
- return nothing ... and output the two tallies to standard output?
- do something else?

Once you've made up your mind:

- code the method to do what you've decided it should do, and
- chose a method name that correctly reflects what it is supposed to do.  Hint: a method that starts with `get` is conventionally a "getter" that *returns* the attribute or attributes themselves ... not a String rendering.

---

`double` is a bad choice of type for a vote count too:

- You cannot have a fractional vote.
- You want to represent vote counts precisely and floating point types (like `double`) are not precise.  (Or at least, not in the sense that you require.)
- When you attempt to format or output a `double`, the resulting character string is likely to include a pesky decimal point ... or worse.

You should use `int` or `long` instead of `double`.

---

Finally, this is a serious Java style violation, and should get you a significant penalty if your marker is paying attention.

```
    private double Democrats;
    private double Republicans;
```

Variable names in Java should start with a LOWER CASE letter.

Answer (score 2):

A few more random comments:

- `import java.lang.String;` is superfluous as all classes in package `java.lang` are automatically imported in every Java source file.
- Votes can not be fractional.  People can't vote 0.75 candidate A, and 0.25 candidate B.  If you use integer datatypes (`int` or `long`), you will be reflecting this fact better.  Also, you will be saving yourself a lot of headache when you start obtaining results like `379857.999999`.  This is because floating point types have a better range, but worse precision (especially noticeable when working with pure integers).
- According to Java usual naming conventions, variable names should start with a lowecase letter.
- A better name for function `getTallies` is `printTallies`.
- For output purposes, it's much better to use string formatting than concatenation.  Some advantages are: multiple formats supported, ease of use, and internationalization.

Putting all together:

```
private int democratVotes;  
private int republicanVotes;

public void printTallies() {
    System.out.format("Democrats: %,d%n",democratVotes);
    System.out.format("Republicans: %,d%n",republicanVotes);
}
```

In this particular case, votes will be printed with thousand separation (ex: `3,345,623` instead of `3345623`). Check Java's [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) tutorial.

Thinking better about it, there are some alternatives where `getTallies` would effectively be returning some form of value:

1) Make it to return a `String` with both tallies.  It would be hard and inefficient to separate the tallies later, though.

```
public String getTallies() {
    return "Democrats: %,d votes.  Republicans: %,d votes.%n".format(democratVotes,republicanVotes);
}
```

2) Make it to return an array.

```
public int[] getTallies() {
    return new int[2]{ democratVotes, republicanVotes };
}
public int[] getTallies1() {  // Same as getTallies, but written step by step.
    int[] result= new int[2] ;
    result[0]= democratVotes ;
    result[1]= republicanVotes ;
    return result ;
}
```

3) Make it to return a class.

```
public VotingMachineResults getTallies() {
    return VotingMachineResults(democratVotes,republicanVotes) ;
}

public static class VotingMachineResults {
    private int democratVotes;
    private int republicanVotes;
    public VotingMachineResults(democratVotes,republicanVotes) {
        this.democratVotes= democratVotes ;    // `this` required to disambiguate field democratVotes from parameter democratVotes.
        this.republicanVotes= republicanVotes ;
    }
    public int getDemocratVotes() {
        return democratVotes ;
    }
    public int getRepublicanVotes() {
        return republicanVotes ;
    }
}
```

As you can see, this class is very similar to `VotingMachine1`, but it does not accept internal state changes.  It is a "value" class.

Comment: I believe you want `VotingMachineResults.getRepublicanVotes()` to be `public`, not `private`.

Comment: @Istvan Chung  Thanks much.  Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you concatenate Strings with the `+` operator. Proper syntax for what you were trying to do looks like this:

```
System.out.println("Democrats: " + Democrats);
System.out.println("Republicans: " + Republicans);
```

A return statement is only used when you want to return some object or value to a method that called your current method. It is not appropriate in this place since you're only passing a value to another method (`println()`).

ALSO, you need to fix your `getTallies()` method. Make it return `void` instead of `double` since you aren't returning anything.

Comment: yes but for some reason I cant use the System.out.println. Why not?

Comment: What do you mean you can't use it? What happens when you try to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something completely different:  why not override `toString()`?

Presumably, any instance of `VotingMachine1` will apply for all votes that you care about for that instance.  That is to say, you don't create a new instance of a `VotingMachine1` every time someone casts a vote.

So, what you can do is override the `toString()` method.  We'll also use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...) to handle the numerical values.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // assumes that Democrats and Republicans are declared as int
    // since it's pointless to indicate percentages of a vote
    return String.format("Democrats: %d\nRepublicans: %d", Democrats, Republicans);
}
```

Now, whenever you vote, you can use the `toString()` method to get the information (which is called whenever one does `System.out.println(object)`.

```
VotingMachine1 voter = new VotingMachine1();
voter.voteDemocrat();
voter.voteRepublican();
System.out.println(voter);
/* This prints:
    Democrats: 1
    Republicans: 1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

A less specific answer to your question would be to return an Object called (say) Votes

```
public class Vote {
  int democratVotes
  int republicanVotes
}
```

and then make your VotingMachine class simply return an instance of this object (suitably changed to make it immutable).

On my project we have created a generic version of this called a Tuple that returns a pair of values in a single object - it has an overloaded toString method for easy printing.

Answer (score 0):

you can return an array with [0] and [1] as key and devide it on the basis of your need..

like

`returnArray[0]="first string";
returnArray[1]="second string";`

```
and use it ur way...
```